# Android mail without intents using Android Mail API

Tags: android

I am using an function to attach image to an email.

```
 public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

  }
```

I call this function when attaching images to email.
When I try to remove the attachment it is not possible.

```
 public void removeAttachment(String filename) throws Exception { 
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

    _multipart.removeBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 

  }
```

Tried with this function but not working.

```
 public void AddAndRemoveAttachment(String filename, Boolean yesorno)throws Exception{
      BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart(); 
      DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
      if(yesorno == true ){

        source = new FileDataSource(filename); 
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source)); 
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename); 

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
      }
      else{

          _multipart.removeBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
      }
  }
```

But the removeBodyPart is not removing the attached image.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I was a little bit conufsed the last time I posted this answer and I took you absolutely wrong! it is indeed correct as you tried it to implement. According to the link I posted in my comment, did you read the documentation for `Multipart`? it says that the `removeBodyPart(BodyPart part)` method throws at least a `MessagingException` if no such `BodyPart` exists. have you tried to catch this `Exception` and write to `Log`?

```
public void removeAttachment(String filename) {
    BodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource src = new FileDataSource(filename);
    part.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(src));
    part.setFileName(filename);

    try {
        _multipart.removeBodyPart(part);
    } catch(MessagingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Got Exception while removing BodyPart: " + e.toString(), e)
    }
}
```

your second guess won't remove anything from your `_multipart` because your just adding the `DataHandler` and setting a filename if your `boolean` is `true`. if it's `false` you're just removing an empty `BodyPart` object.

otherwise, if you want to write your own mail client with user interaction, why don't you add the files which should be attached in an array and do updates on this array? so you can add and remove files from this array and attach the files all at once when the message is going to be sent.

Comment: thanks, can you give me an example, see the edited question with new function but didnt work.

Comment: perhaps this will help a little bit: http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Multipart.html

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that creating a new bodypart and using that as handle to call the removebodypart will work. Isn't there a function to retrieve the existing bodypart and then remove it?

Looks like you are using the wrong argument for it.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you're adding something to your `MultiPart` or does it throw an `Exception` too?

I searched for javax.mail tutorials a bit and found the following: http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_(no_Intents)_in_Android

the author of this tutorial mentions in his `Mail` constructor, that

> There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.

and adds the following:

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822"); 
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

with this it should work as the tutorial did work "out of the box" for me... hope this helps a little bit

Comment: thanks exactly that is what I am using. I am using multipart, it is working for me also but could not remove the attachment. I would like to know any other mail api we can use for android application.

Comment: if you want to remove the last added `BodyPart` you could also use the `removeBodyPart(int index)` function of `Multipart`, if it's that what you want, or consider to have an file array `File[]` which you can update and add the `BodyParts` from this once the mail should be sent...